# find the minimum and maximum value in array group php

Tags: php, arrays, max, minimum, array-reduce

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [package] => LTE_15AGB
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 52690
                    [1] => 24700
                    [2] => 43972
                    [3] => 506417
                    [4] => 488125
                    [5] => 935918
                    [6] => 1322816
                    [7] => 1189040
                    [8] => 2805279
                    [9] => 2764825
                    [10] => 1688294
                    [11] => 1228812
                    [12] => 2232345
                    [13] => 3356143
                    [14] => 1193213
                    [15] => 167589
                    [16] => 1373104
                    [17] => 691411
                    [18] => 1398647
                    [19] => 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [package] => LTE_15AGB_NT
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 953370
                    [1] => 151168
                    [2] => 37605
                    [3] => 428769
                    [4] => 755222
                    [5] => 1146719
                    [6] => 494289
                    [7] => 889002
                    [8] => 307200
                    [9] => 127972
                    [10] => 2764815
                    [11] => 1426224
                    [12] => 262669
                    [13] => 648757
                    [14] => 1485
                    [15] => 1202
                    [16] => 998
                    [17] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($arrayName as $arg){ 
    $tmp[$arg['package']][] = $arg['value']; 
}

$output = array();
foreach($tmp as $type => $labels){
    $output[] = array( 'package' => $type, 'value' => $labels, ); 
}

print_r(($output))
```

Comment: Where is your code? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: yes sir i couldn't add properly

Comment: my code is  $tmp = array();
 foreach($arrayName as $arg){
     $tmp[$arg['package']][] = $arg['value'];
 }
  $output = array();
 foreach($tmp as $type => $labels){
     $output[] = array(
         'package' => $type,
         'value' => $labels,
     );
 }
 print_r(($output));

Comment: Please add your code in your question.

Comment: i want to find a minimum and maximum values for each package group..please help me sir

Comment: loop through array , use [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) functions to get values

Comment: i want to find a minimum and maximum values for each package group..please help me sir 
 [package]=>LTE_15AGB
 minimum=xxxx
 maximum=xxxx

 [package]=>LTE_5AGBNT
 minimum=xxxx
 maximum=xxxx
sorry for the trouble.. im newbie 

this is what i tried code
$resultnew = array_reduce($output, function($memo, $el) {
   if($memo[0] < $el['value']) {
     $memo = array($el['value'], $el);
   }
   return $memo;
 }, array(0, null));

 print_r($resultnew[1]);

Comment: @ArebhySri have you found suitable solution in any of those three answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($your_array as $subarr) {
    echo $subarr[package]." minimum = ";
    echo min($subarr[value])." and maximum = ";
    echo max($subarr[value])."<br>";
 }
```

this will output each package name together with the minimum and maximum values.

Answer (score 1):

@Arebhy Sri, You should search about array in php, It's like basic problem.

```
$finalArray = [];    
foreach ($mainArr as  $subArr){
        $array = $subArr['value'];
        sort($array);

        $tempArray['minimum'] = reset($array);
        $tempArray['maximum'] = end($array);
        $tempArray['package'] = $subArr['package'];
        $finalArray[] = $tempArray;
    }



$finalArray //you can use
```

I am using simple `foreach` and two functions of array `reset()` and `end()`.

> reset(): Returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is empty.
>
> end(): Returns the value of the last element or FALSE for empty array.

Comment: thank you sir..but 
 
i want to find a minimum and maximum values for each package group..please help me sir                                           [package]=>LTE_15AGB minimum=xxxx maximum=xxxx [package]=>LTE_5AGBNT minimum=xxxx maximum=xxxx      sorry for the trouble.. im newbie this is what i tried code                               $resultnew = array_reduce($output, function($memo, $el) { if($memo[0] < $el['value']) { $memo = array($el['value'], $el); } return $memo; }, array(0, null)); print_r($resultnew[1])

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `min()` and `max()` functions.

**Your code**:

```
foreach(array_column($array, 'value') as $key => $values){
    echo PHP_EOL . 'SubArray '. $key .' min = '. min($values) . ' and max value = '.  max($values);
}
```

**output is**:

> SubArray 0 min = 5 and max value = 3356143
>   SubArray 1 min = 1 and max value = 2764815

**References:**

- [PHP min() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)
- [PHP max()) manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)
- [PHP array_column
  manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

**Live demo:** https://eval.in/941702

Comment: `array_column()` is not necessary if you are going to iterate the array anyhow.  All `eval.in` links are now dead.